# Bracket notation with Object.hasOwnProperty?

Tags: javascript

So I was reading through Javascript: The Definitive Guide and was reviewing this simple function:

```
function merge(o, p){
    for(prop in p){
        if(o.hasOwnProperty[prop]) continue;
        o[prop] = p[prop];
    }
    return o;
}
```

Seems simple enough, but when I run it it does not work unless I change `o.hasOwnProperty[prop]` to `o.hasOwnProperty(prop)`.

This makes sense to me since hasOwnProperty is a method. Does this mean that this is just a mistake in the book? I'm reading the 6th edition, and this is printed on page 127 for those interested.

I suspect it is, but I just want to be sure there's not something strange about this function that I'm just not aware of that would make it work.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean that this is just a mistake in the book?

Yes. That's really surprising.

`o.hasOwnProperty[prop]` is valid code, just not what Flanagan meant to use there. (It looks for a property with the name from the `prop` variable on the `hasOwnProperty` function object.)

Please tell me he declared `prop` somewhere as well. It's not declared in your quoted code, thus making the code seem to fall prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Comment: Thanks. I just found the Eratta for the book and I see someone else has already reported this (though its unconfirmed as of now): http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errataunconfirmed.csp?isbn=9780596101992.

Comment: @Plato: Right. It's not declared. (There should be a `var prop` somewhere in `merge`.)

Comment: I think Crockford is innocent, the author is David Flanagan :- http://www.amazon.co.uk/JavaScript-Definitive-Guide-David-Flanagan/dp/0596101996

Comment: @net.uk.sweet: Gah! I read "The Good Parts"! Surely that was a ninja edit!